# How can data stored using the IE userData Behavior deleted?

Tags: internet-explorer

I can't find information about how to delete data stored with the [IE userData Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424(v=VS.85).aspx), other than deleting an individual item with JS.

Is it cleared when a user deletes cookies and html 5 localStorage, or does it need to be deleted in some other way?

Answer (score 4):

IE store userData in
XP:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\UserData
```

or

```
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\UserData
```

Vista/Win7:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\UserData
```

You can find folders and *.dat files and XML files containing data In UserData folder. You can delete them directly, and clear cookies or html 5 localStorage will not work.

Comment: Neither folder you suggest exists for me on XP SP3 with IE 8 (and I've definitely saved stuff to IE UserData on this machine), nor is there a folder called UserData anywhere under C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\

Comment: @lgaud Have you unchecked the folder option "**Hide protected operating system files (Recommeded)**" and checked the folder option "**Show hidden file, folders, and drivers**"? If not, just do those. You can find **those options** in any folder's menubar => Tools => Folder Option => View. Good Luck.

Comment: I just tried **IE userData Behavior** on XP SP3. My username is lengleng on XP. After visting  [the exmaple](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/persistence/userData_1.htm) in the MSDN with IE6, the UserData folder appears under _C:\Documents and Settings\lengleng_. Maybe you can try this site.

Comment: I installed IE8 just now. After visting [the exmaple](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/persistence/userData_1.htm) in the MSDN with IE8, the UserData folder still appears under **C:\Documents and Settings\lengleng**. What the difference between IE8 and IE6 is that the UserData folder created by IE8 has a *hidden* attribute. So, I think the first comment I added can explain why you cannot find the folder.

Comment: Maybe you can find **UserData** directory with this path **C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\UserData**, which I found just now in another XP system.

Comment: On XP, you can find the UserData XML files in C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\UserData\ABCDEFGH.

ASCDEFGH can be any collection of numbers and letters. In these folders you'll find the name of your IE UserData files (eg. myUserData[1].xml if I called my userData 'myUserData')